mdls / mdfind mismatch
If I run mdls(1) here, it correctly shows the metadata for the file, in particular the kMDItemFSName:
 12:28:18 -0400  sshulmanlaniel@StevesMac  /opt/baz/bin/.pk/foo-0.0.34/lib/python3.11/site-packages/foo_client_py/pb  mdls ./foo_pb2.py | grep kMDItemFSName
kMDItemFSName              = "foo_pb2.py"

But if I try to find that file using mdfind(1), it's not returned:
 12:29:39 -0400  sshulmanlaniel@StevesMac  /opt/baz/bin/.pk/foo-0.0.34/lib/python3.11/site-packages/foo_client_py/pb  mdfind -onlyin . "kMDItemFSName == 'foo_pb2.py'"  | wc -l

       0

I could use mdutil -E to regenerate Spotlight metadata on the whole volume, but that seems excessive; there's plenty of perfectly good metadata on this volume already. It's just these few files that are causing a problem. And apparently Spotlight has generated metadata for them already, as evidenced by the mdls command above; the MD just isn't in the index yet.
So what's the trick to get these files indexed?
The reason I'm fiddling with mdls/mdfind at all is that I've long had dreams of writing indexed alternatives to find(1) and grep(1). E.g., if I'm in a git repo, use git grep instead of grep to find what I want quickly; if I'm on a Mac, use mdfind -onlyin /path instead of find /path; if I'm on a Linux box, use locate. But then these weird lacunae show up, where some file that I know exists isn't in the index, and so I need to fall back to find and grep. So the indexed tools are unpredictable enough (at least to me) that I can't use them.
